# XNA Rotate and Move Sprite

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone

```
public class dgc_Spaceship : DrawableGameComponent
{

    Texture2D shipTexture;
    Rectangle spriteRectangle;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    //
    bool horizisSelected = false;
    bool rotateSelected = false;
    bool fireisSelected = false;

    SpriteFont Count;

    //Controls for ship
    dgc_TriggerHorizontal triggerHorizantal;



    Vector2 spritePosition;
    Vector2 spriteOrigin;
    Vector2 direction;


    float rotation = 0.1f;
    Random x, y;


   List<Missle> missleCollection = new List<Missle>();
   List<Asteriod> asteriodCollection = new List<Asteriod>();


    Missle missle;

    Asteriod asteriod;

    public dgc_Spaceship(Game game)
        : base(game)
    {
        // TODO: Construct any child components here


        triggerHorizantal = new dgc_TriggerHorizontal(game);
        triggerHorizantal.triggerHorizantal += new EventHandler(triggerHorizantal_Handler);
        triggerHorizantal.triggerRotate +=new EventHandler(triggerHorizantal_triggerRotate);
        triggerHorizantal.triggerFire +=new EventHandler(triggerHorizantal_triggerFire);
        Game.Components.Add(triggerHorizantal);
        missle = new Missle(game);
        asteriod = new Asteriod(game);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            missleCollection.Add(new Missle(game));
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            asteriodCollection.Add(new Asteriod(game));
        }


      }




    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game component to perform any initialization it needs to before starting
    /// to run.  This is where it can query for any required services and load content.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization code here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        shipTexture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Sprites\spaceship");
        spritePosition = new Vector2(450,320);
        missle.LoadContent();

        Count = Game.Content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"Sprites\Count");
        //
        x = new Random();
        y = new Random();

        foreach (Asteriod display in asteriodCollection)
        {
            display.LoadContent();

            int xVec = x.Next(0, 200), yVec = y.Next(0, 200);
            display.position = new Vector2(xVec, yVec);
        }





        base.LoadContent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game component to update itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // TODO: Add your update code here

        spriteRectangle = new Rectangle((int)spritePosition.X, (int)spritePosition.Y, shipTexture.Width, shipTexture.Height);

        spriteOrigin = new Vector2(spriteRectangle.Width / 2, spriteRectangle.Height / 2);

        direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation));


        if (horizisSelected)
        {
           spritePosition.X-= 0.5f;
           spritePosition.Y-= 0.5f;

        }


        if (rotateSelected)
        {               
            rotation += 0.1f;
           // missle.rotateSprite(); 
            spritePosition += direction * 20 * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        }

        if (fireisSelected)
        {
            missle.update();
        }



        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        spriteBatch.Begin();
      //  missle.draw(spriteBatch,rotation);
        spriteBatch.Draw(shipTexture,spritePosition,null,Color.White,rotation,spriteOrigin,1f,SpriteEffects.None,0);
      //  spriteBatch.DrawString(Count,asteriodCollection.Count.ToString(),new Vector2(100,100),Color.Red);
        foreach (Asteriod display in asteriodCollection)
        {
            display.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
         spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }


    public void triggerHorizantal_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Stuff
        horizisSelected = !horizisSelected;

    }

    public void triggerHorizantal_triggerRotate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Stuff
        rotateSelected = !rotateSelected;
    }

    public void triggerHorizantal_triggerFire(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Stuff
        fireisSelected = !fireisSelected;
    }




    }
}
```

**My Problem:**

I can't seem to figure this out. I have 2 functional buttons on screen. When clicked, the ship rotates clockwise and the other moves it forward. A little searching around lead me to the formula with the Math.Sin/Cos, but I don't think I implemented it properly.

What I need it to do is move the ship in the direction of the rotation.

**The way it works:**
The user will hit the rotate button and it will rotate ship clockwise. When its in a position the user wants, they hit the rotate button to stop it in that particular direction.

The hit the horizontal button and it will move the ship forward in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code suggests that you move your sprite in the direction desired when rotate is selected, this needs to be done when horizontal is selected instead, if rotate is selected then your direction should be changed (not every frame)

EDIT: (5 minutes max)

```
    if (horizisSelected)
    {
       //spritePosition.X-= 0.5f;
       //spritePosition.Y-= 0.5f;
       spritePosition += direction;// * 20 * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

    }


    if (rotateSelected)
    {               
        rotation += 0.1f;
       // missle.rotateSprite(); 

        direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation));
        //spritePosition += direction * 20 * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
    }
```

If your ship is flying away its probably because of the elapsed time (milliseconds), you will have to debug into that

Comment: Could you help me modify it? When I move the code, the ship disappears.

Comment: Quick question,  how do I increase the speed for the ship moving forward

Comment: Generally your direction vector would be a normalized vector and you would multiply that by the current speed and then by the elapsed game time to make sure you are moving at a constant rate regardless of frame rate.

Comment: @ToddersLegrande The only problem is, when I multiply gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds, the ship disappears. If I just multiply by speed alone it works.

Comment: @Sayse - Is there anyway to use the gameTime to help with the speed?

Comment: @Sylvia - I believe this is the "flying away" he described in his update. Two things: 1 - Make sure you use TotalMilliseconds and not Milliseconds as Milliseconds is only the milliseconds component of the TimeSpan and TotalMilliseconds takes all the time and converts it to milliseconds. 2 - Odds are your ship is just moving too fast and so it disappearing is just leaving the screen. Make sure you normalize the vector so its not influencing the speed at all, then drop your speed down really low to see if it helps.

Comment: You could also try TotalSeconds as that would be a smaller number than TotalMilliseconds

Comment: @SylviaRosemond You need to apply some form of modifier to your direction (I've left it commented out in the example), you could have a look at http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thewizard/theWizard.shtml which will probably give you a very good way to do it..